# how can I define a variable in jquery and put a element on it?

Tags: jquery, html

how can I define a variable in jquery and put a element on it?
what's the rule?
i'm new in jquery
my html code is

```
<head>
    <title>Simplify, Simplify</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div> Remember!
        <ul>
            <li>
                <ol>
                    <li>Start with the function keyword</li>
                    <li>Inputs go between ()</li>
                    <li>Actions go between {}</li>
                    <li>jQuery is for chumps!</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>Inputs are separated by commas.</li>
            <li>Inputs can include other functions!</li>
        </ul>
    </div>   
</body>
```

and my jquery is:

```
var target = $("#li:nth-child(4)");
$target.fadeOut('fast');
```

i want to fade #4 line in list order

Answer (score 1):

You're using variable name as `target` and using it as `$target`, should be same:

```
var target = $("li:nth-child(4)");//if named $target
target.fadeOut('fast');//use $target
```

---

```
target !== $target
```

And yes, list has no id defined in your html so just use `li` as the selector instead of `#li`.

Comment: I don't see any `#li` element in their HTML.

Answer (score 1):

if "#4 line in list order" refers to the the 4th `<li>` in `<ol>`

then you can do:

```
$('ol li:nth-child(4)').fadeOut('fast');
```

Comment: You just wiped out an edit of mine on your post that fixed it up much more than you currently have.

Comment: oh? I'm sorry. didn't notice it. can you fix it again?